Program logged: "Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory" custom Metaplex guard
I was working on a custom candy guard with the Candy guard program from Metaplex
After Changing the size of my guard, I get the following error
> Program logged: "Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory"
> Program consumed: 12029 of 742102 compute units
> Program returned error: "SBF program panicked"

explorer tx hash -> https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3hnFgsUNGVQjGZ1oWC8ePwtSmdKQoLdxfF4hjoxjRTJ4NkpVrBFJVDd8vsykuuabQmb2nbXhjTXKuB2wg7cQNQvk?cluster=devnet

This error is not about the amount of space in the account, but the heap space for the VM being exhausted. If you want more heap space, you'll need to:

request it with the compute budget program's request_heap_frame: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/90d3761b9b335e3546d15ef7f691d8bb9ae6bce9/sdk/src/compute_budget.rs#L36
use a different allocator that can take advantage of the extra bytes. The default allocator starts from the top and goes down, which means that it won't use the extra bytes. Here's the implementation of the default allocator for Solana programs: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/90d3761b9b335e3546d15ef7f691d8bb9ae6bce9/sdk/program/src/entrypoint.rs#L289


It seems that the guards are tied to the space you initialize them with.
Meaning that if you allocate 32 bytes for your guard, you are stuck with that
    fn size() -> usize {
        32 // fee destination
    }

Solution I used when I needed moa space was to crate another guard custom_guard_v2 with the larger space requirements accounted for.
